# What could be causing me to get a "ValueError" when getting the angle of a faces normal?

Tags: python

I have a script that creates seams with coplanar faces (to make lighting maps for UE4)

It works on most objects but some objects give me a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Vector.angle(other): zero length vectors have no valid angle
```

At first I thought it was being caused by overlapping faces, but I have some objects with overlapping faces, but I tested that out and didn't get the same error.

Im gonna include my blender file here with some of the objects that give me the error and the test object that has the overlapping faces but doesn't give me the error.

[Blender Test File](https://cp.sync.com/dl/bc0e86f00/supk93fu-b3m578vw-ehnfbihj-udi56xae)

```
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
face = bm.faces[index]
faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.normal.angle(face.normal) < TOL]
```

That last line is what's giving me the error

Does anyone know what about these objects are giving me the error?

Comment: How do you get the angle?

Comment: Hi. Please include any relevant code in the question body so people can easily test your code. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question and added the part that's giving me the error.